# Почему мой sql запрос через node-postgres ничего не делает?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, postgresql

Скрипт должен создавать новую строчку, но при запуске не происходит ничего, ни ошибки, ни новой строчки. В чем может быть дело?

```js
const pg = new pgModule.Client({
    user: 'zephyr',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'campfire',
    password: config.bdPass,
    port: 5432,
})

pg.query(`INSERT INTO public.users (id, money) VALUES ('521048525102907408', 100);`, (err, res) => {
if(err){
    console.log(err.stack);
} else {
    console.log(res)
}});
pg.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему заменив Client на Pool, все сразу заработало)

Comment: т.е. вам помогло `const pg = new pgModule.Pool({` ?

Comment: @gil9red Да, так и есть